# Mocking and Stubbing protractor $http call when interceptors are present

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I try to use $httpBackend to mock all api calls . I'm using interceptors to transform response and request like this

```
var factory = function HttpInterceptorFactory () {
    return {
      request: function request (config) {
        config = _.assign(config, cfg.httpConfiguration);
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        return config;
      },
      response: function response (response) {
        return (response.config['verbose']) ? response.data.content : response;
      }
    };
  };
```

And then in angular application I'm doing:

```
A.module(cfg.ngApp).config([
    '$httpProvider',
    function ($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptorFactory');
    }]
  )
```

How can I mock stuff and then push it though interceptor because what I see $httpBackend is going straight to $http and ignoring interceptor.

Comment: What if you would use [`protractor-http-mock`](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock) instead?

Comment: This is problem I try to use it but protractor-http-mock also not taking into consideration interceptor . Now I try to "fix" it because protractor-http-mock only returning data that isn't put though interceptor.Inside http-mock.js there is not injector 'httpProvider' to transform request before and after.